# OpenSSL how to load CA cert with DER format

Tags: c, openssl, x509

I am new to OpenSSL, so forgive me if I ask anything stupid.

I need to convert an existing server project which uses axTLS to OpenSSL. As the server requires client authentication, I need to load the server cert file, private key file and the CA cert file. All 3 files are in DER format.

For server cert file and private key file, I can use `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file()` and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file()` to load a DER format file (ASN1 format). However, I couldn't find any API that loads the CA cert in DER format. `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` and `SSL_load_client_CA_file()` seem only work for PEM format.

Any other API/method I can use to work around this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: According to the [document](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_load_client_CA_file.html), it supports only PEM format.

Comment: So it means there is no way for OpenSSL API to load a DER format (.cer file extension) CA cert?? I am having a difficult time to convince myself this as axTLS is able to do it and axTLS is supposed to be a 'lite' version of SSL implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question. As what Yu Hao said, there seems to be no API available in OpenSSL to load a CA cert in DER(ANS1) format. I had to get the PEM format version of CA cert to use in the end.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, DER files can have `.crt`, `.cer`, and `.der` endings.

As for your question it may be one of many issues. Does your existing server project already work, and to what extent?

Could you first try and convert the DER file to PEM and tell us how it went?

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

Comment: The existing server project is already working perfectly working with other clients which are also using axTLS. Sorry that I am new to SSL and I am not sure what result you want to see for the conversion. The DER file (.cer) is converted from PEM format in the first place. The server and the clients choose to use DER format because of some limitation on the client platform.

Comment: @AngelaYan Could you post the code that fails, not just the API methods that are in use please.

Comment: I don't have the code that 'fails' because I am still trying to figure out what API I should use to load a DER format CA cert. So far I can only find these 2 API are used for loading CA cert: `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` and `SSL_load_client_CA_file()`. But from the documentation, both API only supports PEM format CA cert only. Do you mean despite what the documentation says I should still try to use these 2 API to see if they can load the DER format CA cert?

Comment: @AngelaYan First use `SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb()` to set the (if any) server certificate password, then use `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file()` to load the server certificate, then use `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file()` to load the private key file, then use `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` to verify with trusted CA'a, then use `BIO_new_file()` and `PEM_read_bio_DHparams()` and `SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh()` to load DH paramenters from a file, then use `SSL_get_verify_result()` to verify the peer X509 certificate, and finally `SSL_get_peer_certificate()` to get the certificate from the peer.

Comment: @AngelaYan One more thing, you should probably also verify the peer with `SSL_set_verify()`.

Comment: Thank you Inge. You are very detail, although you did not seem to answer my question.

Comment: @AngelaYan Yes I did answer your question. My _very_ first suggestion was **Could you first try and convert the DER file to PEM and tell us how it went? `openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem`** - see my reply - it's there in black and white... And you said in _your own solution_ that _you_  solved it by using a PEM certificate since DER was not supported.